# cordova-plugin-media-capture not working in Chrome browser

Tags: android, cordova, typescript

I created an application using Cordova and cordova-plugin-media-capture. The application is not working in Chrome Browser version 56.0. But it is working in Firefox 51.0.

On Chrome browser on Android phone,  I'm not able to access the camera using navigator.device.capture.captureImage() but on Firefox it is working. I'm using latest version of cordova (6.5.0) and latest version of plugin. In Firefox, it gives a warning, that API is using a deprecated method MediaStream.stop().
Kindly provide a solution how to make this application work on Chrome. Is this the issue of version of Chrome browser or cordova API?

Answer (score 0):

MediaStream.stop() API is using a deprecated.
Change

```
MediaStream.stop()
```

to

```
MediaStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
```